# Check how fast numpy.linalg.lstsq is finding convergence

Tags: numpy

I have a question concerning NumPy module linalg.lstsq(a,b). There is any possibility to check how fast this method is finding convergence? I mean some of characteristics which indicate how fast computation is going to convergence?
Thank you in advanced for brain storm.

Answer (score 5):

The Numpy function `linalg.lstsq` uses singular value decomposition (SVD) to solve the least-square problem. Thus, if your matrix `A` is `n` by `n`, it will require `n^3` flops.

More precisely, I think that the function uses the Householder Bidiagonalization to compute the SVD and so, if your matrix is `m` by `n`, the complexity will be `O(max(m, n) * min(m, n)^2)`.